# Rmd: Can I produce a new line within an R chunk that doesn't appear as R Comment in a Word Document?

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, newline

do you have any solutions to producing a blank line within an Rchunk in Rmd? I want to put it out as a word document.

Currently I am doing this:

```
flextable(table1)
cat("  \n")
flextable(table2)
```

But this doesn't produce a line between the tables. If I do this instead:...

```
flextable(table1)
cat("Some Text")
flextable(table2)
```

... I get a line between the tables, but it's with a grey background and leading "##  ".

I don't want to use seperate Rchunks, because I want to write a function that allows me to print multiple tables at once seperated by a blank space.
Do you have any ideas?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set the chunk option `results='asis'` such that

> text output is written “as-is”, e.g., you can write out raw Markdown
>   text from R code

[Xie, Yihui, Joseph J. Allaire, and Garrett Grolemund. R markdown: The definitive guide. Chapman and Hall/CRC, 2018.](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html)

and also make sure the output from `cat` is not in conflict with `flextable` output. Adding `\n` on each side of `\\newline` seems to work. We then have the chunk

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
flextable(mtcars[1:4, ])
cat("\n \\newline \n")
flextable(mtcars[1:4, ])
```
````

`results='asis'` might come in conflict with some  other stuff. If this is the case, you can omit this option and use `knitr::asis_output()` only at the desired output

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
flextable(mtcars[1:4, ])
knitr::asis_output("\n \\newline \n")
flextable(mtcars[1:4, ])
```
````